# Updating multiple records with CAML/jQuery to Sharepoint (Batch updating)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to update multiple records in Share Point using jQuery and CAML. I can update a single record easily with this code but for this project, I need to update 20 Products at a time. I suppose I could loop and call this function 20 times, but I figure there must be a more elegant solution that would hopefully complete the task in a single request.

There are 20 Select boxes for each survey named "Prod_1", "Prod_2", ... , "Prod_20".

```
function saveProducts() {

        var sList = "ProductData"
        var i = 1;

        var sQry = "";
        sQry += "<Batch OnError='Continue'>";
        sQry += "   <Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>";
        sQry += "     <Field Name='ID'>" + $("#uniqueID").val() + "</Field>";
        sQry += "     <Field Name='Offered'>" + $("#Prod_1").val() + "</Field>";
        sQry += "   </Method>";
        sQry += "</Batch>";

        var request = "";
        request += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'";
        request += " xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'";
        request += " xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>";
        request += " <soap:Body>";
        request += " <UpdateListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
        request += " <listName>" + sList + "</listName>";
        request += " <updates>" + sQry + "</updates>";
        request += " </UpdateListItems>";
        request += " </soap:Body>";
        request += "</soap:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            async: false, url: sURL, type: "POST", dataType: "xml", data: request, contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"); },
            complete: function processSaveProducts(xData, status) {
                //alert("Save Status: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to do this with a single update instead of running this code 20 times? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest multiple `<Method>` nodes within the same `<Batch>`:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" 
ViewName="270C0508-A54F-4387-8AD0-49686D685EB2">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">4<Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>
   <Method ID="2" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID" >6</Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. I only needed to add a simple for loop around the Method to get all 20 responses.